# implement for and if in reduce funtion

Tags: python-3.x, mapreduce

I want to know how to fetch a specific key-value from a `list of object` using reduce function.

let say I am passing a list of objects to reduce function and each object has a key `number` and value is `some integer`, so `I want a sum of all values`.

sample data is like

```
result = [{'number':1},{`number`:2},{'number':3}]
```

so in reduce I have code where `key` is result and `value` is `[objects,..]`, **how should I achieve this?**

```
reduce = Code(
    """
    function(key,value)
    {
        return Array.sum(value);
    }
    """
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from functools import reduce
result = [{'number':1},{"number":2},{'number':3}]
c = reduce(lambda x,y:{"number":x['number']+y['number']}, result)
print(c)

"you can also use list comprehensions"

target = sum(i['number'] for i in result)
print(dict(number=target))
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your quick response, code is working fine for me.